# Installing programs via shell script; programs not found?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script so that I can quickly install dependencies on fresh virtual machines via OpenStack. I have written these dependencies in a script file but upon running, I receive the following error for each one:

```
E: unable to locate package ***
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: unable to locate package ****
```

and so on. I'm not sure what's going wrong, as I know the packages I've listed exist, and running sudo apt-get install *** (with the package names in the file) works as expected. My shell file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash      
#shell script for installation on a VM
#i've never written a shell script before so bear with me please

apt-get update
apt-get --assume-yes install build-essential
apt-get --assume-yes install git
apt-get --assume-yes install make
apt-get --assume-yes install xclip
apt-get --assume-yes install python
apt-get --assume-yes install liblapack-dev
apt-get --assume-yes install libblas-dev
apt-get --assume-yes install libboost-dev
apt-get --assume-yes install libarmadillo-dev
```

and I'm running it as sudo bash freshinstallscript.sh.

Comment: do you have a repository properly configured?

Comment: extract your environment to a file from the cmd line with `set > cmdLine.env` and add similar to top of your shell script, i.e. `set >script.env` Then compare them, `comm cmdLine.env script.env` Maybe you'll find the difference in the first or second columns (3rd columns are data found in both files). Good luck.

Comment: Silly question, here -- how did you write this script? If it has DOS newlines, that would explain the bug -- there may exist a package named `xclip`, but there one won't be one named `xclip$'\r'`, which is what you'd get if you wrote this script in Windows with Notepad and copied it over instead of using a native UNIX text editor.

Comment: That said, if you have that bug, you'd get other errors **before** the `unable to locate package` ones. Providing only a partial log means we don't have enough info in this question to check for them and thus validate the theory.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue; it seemed to be related to line endings. To fix, I installed dos2unix and converted the shell file.